# Argument of type 'Observable<xyz[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, unknown>'

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

The error `Argument of type 'Observable<HistoryBranch[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, unknown>'.` is being thrown by

```
// private historyBranches$: Observable<historyBranches[]>;

this.historyBranches$ =  this.timeline$.pipe(
            switchMap((tmln) => this.getHistoryBranches$(tmln)));
```

`this.getHistoryBranches` is implemented as:

```
    private getHistoryBranches$(timelineData: Timeline[]): Observable<HistoryBranch[]> {
        return this.service.getHistoryBranches({
                startTime: timelineData[0].time,
                endTime: timelineData[timelineData.length - 1].time,
            }).pipe(map(response=>response.HistoryBranches));
    }
```

What is this `OperatorFunction`? (documentation didn't really clarify much for me.. https://rxjs.dev/api/index/interface/OperatorFunction)
Why is there a type mismatch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is probably related to the returned value of the `getHistoryBranches` method

Double check it's return type, and also that the value of `response` is what you expect. That looks a bit off, but you'd need to post code for the service function tod someone to be sure